# C Segmentation fault: 11 error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am rather new to C and although this code compiles (using `gcc -Wall -o test test.c`), running `./test` just results in the output `dbecher$: Segmentation fault: 11`. Does anybody know what might cause this?

Well, I know instead of using a pointer I could just assign a normal struct, but I am using this to test some behavior of pointers. So I want to keep using a pointer variable for that struct.

Here the code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct HumidityMessage {
  int nodeId;
  int sequenceNumber;
  int humidity;
} HumidityMessage;

HumidityMessage* packet;

int main() {
    packet->nodeId = 0;
    packet->sequenceNumber = 1;
    packet->humidity = 3;

    printf("This is the address of packet: %d", packet->nodeId);
}
```

Comment: Global variables are initialized to 0. Hence, `packet` is a null pointer. And then you are trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 4):

Segmentation faults are caused by invalid memory accesses.  In this case you're getting it because you're dereferencing the packet pointer without first allocating space for it.

Answer (score 2):

`HumidityMessage* packet;` is pointing to nothing. Initialize it:

```
HumidityMessage* packet = malloc(sizeof(HumidityMessage));
```

Comment: No, it's global so it's initialized to 0.

Comment: it's not pointing to garbage. it's `NULL` because it's global.

Comment: Actually that is what i wrote before - then got confused then corrected myself again lol.

Comment: Ah! of course, I totally forgot that in the beginning the pointer is pointing pretty much to nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a pointer. Use `HumidityMessage packet;` instead.

Currently `packet` is initialised to `nullptr` and it's illegal to dereference that.

Alternatively you could retain the pointer and allocate memory for it before you need it, but finding a place for the corresponding `free` is problematic for globals.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory to the packet pointer using the c inbuilt malloc function. Packet = (HumidityMessage * )malloc(size of(HumidityMessage));
Or you can directly take a variable of the structure and assign the value.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (and family of function)